# Specialize templated function for templated class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

In C++, I am trying to specialize a templated function for a object that is templated itself.

Here is a basic example:
test.h:

```
template <class T>
class myC {
    T x;
};

template <class U>
void f(U y) {
}

template <>
template <class T>
void f<myC<T> >(myC<T> y) {
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
int main() {
    myC<double> m;
    f(m);
}
```

GCC 4.6.1 gives me the following error message:

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
test.h:13:25: error: too many template parameter lists in declaration of ‘void f(myC<T>)’
test.h:13:6: error: template-id ‘f<myC<T> >’ for ‘void f(myC<T>)’ does not match any template declaration
test.h:13:25: note: saw 2 ‘template<>’, need 1 for specializing a member function template
```

Is this at all possible? Or is there another way to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You cannot specialize a template function; only template classes can be specialized.</strike> Edit: Nawaz's answer is correct: it's partial specialization that is not allowed for template functions, only for classes. A full specialization is possible:

```
template <class U> void f(U y) {}
template<> void f<double>(double y) {} // specialization for double
```

Note that the template argument need not be explicitly specified if it can be deduced from the context:

```
template<> void f<>(int y) {} // specialization for int
```

In your case, full specialization is not possible because the function argument is a template class. However, a template function, like any function, can be overloaded. In your case, it will be like this:

```
template <class T>
class myC {
    T x;
};

template <class U>
void f(U y) {
}

template <class T>
void f(myC<T> y) {
}

int main() {
    myC<double> m;
    f(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
template <>
template <class T>
void f<myC<T> >(myC<T> y) {
}
```

What you're atttempting to be doing here is called *partial* specialization which is not allowed in case of function template.

A function template is either *fully* specialized, or not specialized at all. No partial specialization of function template is allowed by the language specification.

So you can *overload* the function template as:

```
template <class T>
void f(myC<T> y)  //note that it is overload, not specialization
{ 
}
```

which is allowed, and preferred over even fully specialization of template.

Read these articles by Herb Sutter:

- [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)
- [Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)

Comment: Wasn't it introduced in C++11?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you cannot specialize template functions, only template classes (or structs).

But that is hardly a limitation: just declare a struct with static public member functions and mave the template parameters to the struct:

```
template <class T>
class myC {
    T x;
};

template <class U>
struct Foo
{
    static void f(U y) {
    }
};

template <>
template <class T>
struct Foo<myC<T> >
{
    static void f(myC<T> y) {
    }
};
```

The drawback is that class templates do not solve the template parameters automatically. But that can be easlily solved with a function template, similar to the original one:

```
template <class U>
void f(U y) {
    return Foo<U>::f(y);
}
```